# TimerJob error missing public constructor

Tags: 2007, development, feature, timer-jobs

I have an issue on my SharePoint 2007 portal, where i created a custom TimerJob, but when I deploy it i get a message:

> MyTimerJob cannot be deserialized because it does not have a
>   public default constructor.

I perfromed a research and i applied some solutions where provided but I still have the same issue!

Here is the code:

```
public CustomTimerJob()
    : base()
 { }

public CustomTimerJob(string name, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType lockType) :
     base(name, service, server, lockType)
  {}

public CustomTimerJob(string name, SPWebApplication webApplication) :
   base(name, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
{
    this.Title = "XML Retriever";
}

public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
{
  //Perfrom work
}
```

And here is my feature activation:

```
    MyTimerJob customTimerJob = new MyTimerJob(JOB_NAME, site.WebApplication);

    SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
    schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
    schedule.EndSecond =50;
    schedule.Interval = 50;
    customTimerJob.Schedule = schedule;

    customTimerJob.Update();
```

Anyone has any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing

```
public CustomTimerJob(string name, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType lockType) :
     base(name, service, server, lockType)
  {}
```

and changing

```
MyTimerJob customTimerJob = new MyTimerJob(JOB_NAME, site.WebApplication);
```

to

```
MyTimerJob customTimerJob = new MyTimerJob(site.WebApplication);
```

Also attach your solution to OWSTimer.EXE and see where exactly its getting stuck.

Hope it helps :)